# How to use Apache Filematch to apply cache control only for particular set of pages comes in the same domain

Tags: apache-2.4

Am trying to set a cache control for css and image. The real problem is i want to do the things within the one domain but only for different URL.

Main domain: https://www.someexample.com/

I want to put the cache control on css and js only for the URL /newchild (that is coming under the domain) and other pages coming under/newpage/1/2.. etc.

https://www.someexample.com/newchild

The cache control should work only is the URL matches https://www.someexample.com/**newchild**

I tried using the below code, but am getting the error on it.

```
<LocationMatch "^/newchild/*.*$">
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
        AddType text/css .css
        AddType text/javascript .js
            <ifModule mod_headers.c>
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1210000, public"
            </ifModule>
    </FilesMatch>
</LocationMatch>
```

For the above code am getting error as FilesMatch cannot occur within LocationMatch section

Am not sure how to fix this. Can some one help me with this approcah.

Many thanks,
SR

Comment: Location is for virtual paths and FilesMatch applies to real files in documentroot, if the "files" are not in your documentroot do not mix them since filesmatch won't match. If at all define files or filesmatch under directory tag instead.

Comment: I tried adding the below 
`<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/newchild">
    <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
        AddType text/css .css
        AddType text/javascript .js
        <ifModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
        </ifModule>
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>`

Still get the error - Syntax error on line 50 of /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/vhost.conf:

all the pages inside the newchild and the newchild page itself will have the css and JS served from /one/two/abd.js and /one/two/abd.css.

Can you please help with this?

Comment: what is "line 50"?

Comment: The error says Directory cant be used with in Filesmatch